# Can I use handwriting personalization in custom .net app

Tags: .net, windows-7, tablet-pc, personalization, handwriting

Windows Vista and 7 both contain the ability to personlize the handwriting recognition.  You can train the tablet to recognize your specific style.

I know the personlization is used by the Native Windows Tablet Input Panel (TIP), the OS's handwriting control.

Does the .NET SDK provide access to this personlization data so that my .net application can use it for the ink based controls in the app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Microsoft.Ink classes. These are Winforms and you can find the DLL at
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Tablet PC\v6.0\Microsoft.Ink.dll

or if you use WPF you can use the InkAnalyzer class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754080.aspx
but I had trouble referencing one of the dlls from a .net 4 assembly. But I found out that adding the following config to the assembly solves the problems.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
   </startup>
  </configuration>
```

Check some info here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tabletandtouch/thread/dccb93b9-5f0e-4824-8e0f-eb7f0b6cab15/